# Cannot find "Deploy app engine project" option on GAE Plugin for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I have an eclipse GAE project created with Eclipse Kepler.
I imported this project to another computer with Eclipse Luna, then installed the GAE plugin and restarted Eclipse.

Now when I try to deploy this project to GAE, I don't even see this option under "Google"section in the right-click menu:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you install the same plugin version, or a newer one, on the Luna Eclipse?

Comment: iirc, there is a small google button in your toolbar that has the option

Comment: mjn, no - this is a newer version.
zapl Thanks! got it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Deploy to App Engine..." option can be found in the toolbar.

[image]

Or via the quick access box (`ctrl + 3` to focus without mouse)

[image]

Whether the toolbar icon appears can depend on the perspective. It should be visible in the "Java" perspective. And in case you managed to remove it, "Window > Perspective > Customize Perspective" and enable it in the toolbar visibility options in the "Google" category or reset the Java perspective to default.